# How to set Meteor.user()

Tags: authentication, meteor

My meteor app uses github authentication. After a user has authenticated

```
Meteor.user()
```

return the current authenticated user (on the client and server).

What I now need is to run my application without authentication. But Meteor.user() should return some user because my code expects it. Is there anyway I can tell my meteor app what Meteor.user() should return ?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor.user() always returns the current user. If there is no user logged in, then Meteor.user() returns null. You cannot change that behavior.

The thing to do then is probably modify your app code in such a way that different code is run when no user is logged in. You can do that like so:

```
if(Meteor.user()){
    //do stuff when user is logged in
}
else{
    //do stuff if user is not logged in
}
```

Comment: You can change the behavior of `Meteor.user` by assigning it a new function. Simple as that! I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: It seems to be the only solution, and it work like a charm :) thnx

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but maybe creating a custom login handle for anonymous user will help. Take a look [here](https://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html) for a very nice explanation by Arunoda on extending Meteor's account system.

Though, I think that the best way to go would be to make your code independent on fact the `Meteor.user()` might be `null`'ish as @fritzi2000 suggested.

Please note that `Meteor.user()` may potentially return `null` even if the user is actually logged in and `Meteor.userId()` is set properly. This is because `Meteor.user()` is more or less equivalent to

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
```

so it relies on some particular data being fetched from the server. Hence, it's always better to verify the logged-in status with `Meteor.userId()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I will definitely read that article!